# React - callbackFromApp function only running once onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When a click a button in my child react module it increments my timer and should pass back the timer in minutes and total seconds back to the parent and stored as state.

When I click the button it only runs once - it doesn't increment on a second click. I want it to run on every click.

https://github.com/nimaiwalsh/Pomodora-Clock/tree/master/src

The following is the my function in the parent to store the state

```
  updateTimer = (minutes, totalSeconds) => {
    this.setState({ minutes: minutes, totalSeconds: totalSeconds});
  }
```

I pass the callback as a prop to my child

```
<SessionLength callbackFromApp={this.updateTimer} />
```

And from my child I have the following

```
const SessionLength = ({ callbackFromApp }) => {

    let minutes = 1;
    let totalSeconds = 0; 

    const addOne = () => {
        minutes += 1;
        totalSeconds = minutes*60;
        console.log(minutes, totalSeconds);
        callbackFromApp(minutes, totalSeconds);
    }
    const removeOne = () => {
        if(minutes >0) {
            minutes -= 1;
            totalSeconds = minutes*60;
        }
        console.log(minutes, totalSeconds);
        callbackFromApp(minutes, totalSeconds);
    }
    return (
        <div className="session-length">
            <button className="minutes-add-btn" onClick={() => addOne()}>+</button>
            <p>{ minutes }</p>
            <button id="minutes-minus-btn" onClick={() => removeOne()}>-</button>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: what do you mean it only runs once? Doesn't it increment the minutes the second time you click?

Comment: Exactly, it doesn't increment on on further clicks

Comment: does parent implement shouldComponentUpdate? And do you render the proper state in the parent? console.log prints correct output?

Comment: I haven't used shouldComponentUpdate in my parent.

I have updated GitHub - https://github.com/nimaiwalsh/Pomodora-Clock/tree/master/src

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that when the parent of `<SessionLength />` gets re-rendered (aka updated via `callbackFromApp`), the following snippet is re-executed once again

```
let minutes = 1;
let totalSeconds = 0;
```

which resets the counter, therefore a difference is not seen after the first click.

Move those variables outside of `<SessionLength />` so that they are not being reset on each update.

Comment: Thankyou! So simple, I was sitting here for hours wrapping my head around it. Obviously still very new with React!

Answer (score 0):

here you are using stateless component. Every time these are initialized and give same output. That's what minutes is not increment.

```
let minutes = 1;let totalSeconds = 0;
```

So maintain in parent state and send to stateless child component.Now you can get output. Find your correction in below code.

```
import React from 'react';

class HeadComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {minutes:1,totalSeconds:0};
      this.updateTimer=this.updateTimer.bind(this);
    }

    updateTimer(minutes, totalSeconds){
        console.log(minutes, totalSeconds);
        this.setState({ minutes: minutes, totalSeconds: totalSeconds});
    }

   render() {
      return (
        <div>
            <h1>Page Header</h1>
            <SessionLength callbackFromApp={this.updateTimer} minutesState={this.state.minutes}/>
            <p>minutes: {this.state.minutes}</p>
            <p>totalSeconds : {this.state.totalSeconds}</p>
        </div>
      );
   }
}

const SessionLength = ({ callbackFromApp,minutesState}) => {
    let minutes=minutesState,totalSeconds=0;
    const addOne = () => {
        minutes = minutesState+1;
        totalSeconds = minutes*60;
        callbackFromApp(minutes, totalSeconds);
    }
    const removeOne = () => {
        if(minutes >0) {
            minutes = minutesState-1;
            totalSeconds = minutes*60;
        }
        callbackFromApp(minutes, totalSeconds);
    }

    return (
        <div className="session-length">
            <button className="minutes-add-btn" onClick={() => addOne()}>+</button>
            <p>{ minutes }</p>
            <button id="minutes-minus-btn" onClick={() => removeOne()}>-</button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default HeadComponent;
```